# Flutter Right way of fetching Data

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and I'm currently trying to learn about fetching data

The Data might look something like this:

```
Data:
-- User1
---- User1Ticket1
-------- Title_text
-------- Title_picture
---- User1Ticket2
-- User2
---- User2Ticket1
---- User2Ticket2
```

I manage to fetch the data from RTDB and set it into a variable, The problem is I cannot useeach of the data because when I want to get the key of User1 and user2.. The data will covered in a double braces like this:

> AllofUsersTicketId: [[user1Ticket1],[user2Ticket1],[user2Ticket2]]

How to fix this ? Here's my code, the **allSolversPowId[j]** is always null because there are braces wrapping each of them:

```
    List solversId = powData.keys.toList();
    List allSolversPowId = [];

    for(int i =0; i < solversId.length; i++){
      allSolversPowId.add(powData[solversId[i]].keys.toList());
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < solversId.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < allSolversPowId.length; j++) {
        calledWidget.add(
           ReusablePositionWidget(
             onTap: (){},
             child: Column(
             children: [
               Text(
                   powData[solversId[i]][allSolversPowId[j]]['pow_text']
               )
             ],
            )
           )
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

By this way you will be able to access the element you need.

```
allSolversPowId[j][0]
```

Because,

`[[user1Ticket1],[user2Ticket1],[user2Ticket2]]` is a List of List.

Change the loop to something like this,

```
 for(int i = 0; i < solversId.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < allSolversPowId[i].length; j++) {
        calledWidget.add(
           ReusablePositionWidget(
             onTap: (){},
             child: Column(
             children: [
               Text(
                   powData[solversId[i]][allSolversPowId[i][j]]['pow_text']
               )
             ],
            )
           )
        );
      }
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you think the for loop is wrong because if I made it like that User2 Will access The PowId of User1Ticket1 or User1Ticket2. Won't it cause null because that TicketId doesn't exist in user2

or I  can just return SizedBox.shrink if that data is null ?

Comment: Can you tell what is powData, solversId and allSolversPowId?

Comment: like the data type ? PowData is map, solversId is the first layer key which a string and allSolversPowId is the secondLayer  key which a String also

Comment: Can you add an example of PowData?

Comment: The same like the example